# ffmpeg php makes system unresponsive

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to create a video on my web application using images as input by the user. 
I am using ffmpeg currently to encode the output. However, my system becomes unresponsive each time I execute the command.

I am using exec command of php and following is my ffmpeg command.

```
ffmpeg -i bg2.png -i overlay1.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=0:0[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y=-'t*w*0.1':shortest=1[v]"  -map "[v]" -t 10 out.mkv
```

I'd appreciate if you could also share some good resources to learn more about ffmpeg on web and other alternatives.

Comment: you want to generate images for that video file?

Comment: I want to generate a video file from those images.

Comment: `scale=0:0` does not make sense. What is the purpose of that? You need to show the complete console output from your command.

Comment: That's not the main problem here. And I've tried other variations too, system still becomes unresponsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multimedia manipulation is an expensive process.  Sounds to me like you need a beefier server.  If that isn't possible, experiment with `nice` values.

Comment: I am working on a windows system. Does `nice` work on windows too?

Comment: @AkshayKhetrapal You can set process priority on Windows... same effect.